# Specify framework/platform in Azure pipeline yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

I want to tell Azure to run tests against the framework and platform actually used by my test project. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#q--a),

> Tests that target the .NET core framework can be executed by specifying the appropriate target framework value.

But how do I do that?

Additionally, the log output says there is an issue of different platforms. I'm not sure how to address that either. I've tried putting a platform into my yml, but it doesn't help.

Here is my current yml:

```
- job: Test
  dependsOn: SetBuildName

  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'

  variables:
    solution: '**/MyTestSolution.sln'
    buildPlatform: 'x86|x64|ARM'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    appxStagingDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'

  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '5.4.0'
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'    

  - task: VersionAPPX@2
    inputs:
      Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      VersionNumber: '$(versionNumber)'
      InjectVersion: true
      OutputVersion: 'OutputedVersion'  

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      platform: 'x86'   #Changing this to AnyCPU had no effect.
      solution: '$(solution)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      msbuildArgs: '/t:Restore'

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      platform: 'x86'
      solution: '$(solution)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)"
                    /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxStagingDir)"
                    /p:AppxBundle=Always
                    /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=Sideload
                    /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true
                    /p:VersionPrefix="$(versionNumber)"
                    /p:VersionSuffix="$(version.SpecialBuild)"
                    /p:SourceRevisionId="$(Build.SourceVersion)"'
```

And here is an excerpt from the log:

```
2020-03-19T12:28:57.5842598Z Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
2020-03-19T12:28:57.5843802Z MyProject.Test.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
```

The best solution would be to tell it to use whatever the project built against. But if that isn't possible, I'd settle for a way to specify NETCoreApp 3.1 and AnyCPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tests that target the .NET core framework can be executed by
>   specifying the appropriate target framework value.

In `VSTest@2` task, there has one argument names `otherConsoleOptions`. It can pass some additional options to the tool `vstest.console.exe`, including **platform**, **framwork** and [etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2017#general-command-line-options).

*Note: The `platfrom` argument of task just purely for **reporting** purposes.*

Here is what I am using on my YAML:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\Release\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    otherConsoleOptions: '/Platform:x86 /Framework:Framework45'
    platform: 'x86|x64'
```

Just replace the `otherConsoleOptions` value based on your actual demand like this:

```
otherConsoleOptions: '/Platform:{platform type: x86/x64/ARM} /Framework:{Framwork version}'
```

---

Above method is used for making `platform/framwork` configuration in `yml` file.

But there has another way you can use to achieve it: specify `platform type` and `framwork version` in your [`runsetting` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#example).

```
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    ...
    ...
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework40</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ....
    ....
  </RunConfiguration>
  ...
...
</RunSettings>
```